# About using wordpress esc_html__

Tags: wordpress

using the esc_html__ function was tiring to write text domain all the time: D so I created a function as below.

The problem is I can get the following word but it doesn't save to .pot file. If I make a direct definition of esc_html__ in the function, it works but when I use variables for dynamics, what is the reason?

```
// Working
function lsph_lang(){
    return esc_html__( "Hello", 'lsph' );
}
lsph_lang();

// Not working.
function lsph_lang( $str ){
    return esc_html__( $str, 'lsph' );
}
lsph_lang( "hello" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just giving you my 2cents about this translation stuff, either you are patient and keep writing the full form like this:

```
esc_html__( "Hello", 'lsph' )
```

Or you "hack it" by making that your "lsph_lang" internally generates a .php temp file which contains ALL the possible variant of your translations stuff. Doing that will ensure that tools that read the translations stuff will work as expected and you can stop writing the full form

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find a solution to this and I will continue to use it as esc_html__.

So how logical would it be to have a static class holding the text to be translated?

Comment: If this answer gave you something to think about mark it as accepted and just develop over it in they way it better fits your project/needs :)